# Unable to connect to database through Eclipse

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I have been trying to run this code for hours, to get no success. I have Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition. Does anyone know the code to get port number from sql * plus cmd prompt?
The code doesn't run and I am not able to view the output over eclipse. Please guide me.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Testt {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try{
            //Driver registration
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            //Create connection
            Connection c =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:
            @localhost:1521:EE","scott","tiger");

            //Create statement
            Statement stmt=c.createStatement();

            //Execute query
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp;");
            while(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2));
            }
            c.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}

}
```

Output:
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Comment: What's the SID of your instance?

Comment: Thats the main point of the discussion. Its particularly something. I tried 11G, EE, ee. Nothing works.

Comment: I got the SID for oracle 11g Enterprise Edition. It is orcl bro. But now I am getting a new error. java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: I got the answer for "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character" as the query has a ; in it. Both the problems got sorted out.

Comment: Run `lsnrctl status` and post the output. It'll tell you what services are available

Comment: No bro. lsnrctl doesn't work. It gives this error: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor.
 I said the SID is orcl and it also gave the perfect output.

Comment: Thank you :) I got two statements correct. 1. Connection c =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","scott","tiger");   2. ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");